# Getting 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric.' even after converting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple sql query

```
select top 100 
    pickticket_number,
    date_allocated,
    l2.action
from  
    [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].PickTickets P (nolock)
left join
    [A1Warehouse].[dbo].[RF_LOG2] (NOLOCK) l2 ON l2.PACKSLIP = p.PickTicket_Number
```

It seems to be a simple converting/casting issue but no matter what conversion or casting I try, I get the same error.

I've tried all of the following

```
LEFT JOIN
    [A1Warehouse].[dbo].[RF_LOG2] (NOLOCK) l2 ON convert(numeric,l2.PACKSLIP) = p.PickTicket_Number

LEFT JOIN
    [A1Warehouse].[dbo].[RF_LOG2] (NOLOCK) l2 ON convert(numeric,l2.PACKSLIP) = convert(numeric, p.PickTicket_Number)

LEFT JOIN
    [A1Warehouse].[dbo].[RF_LOG2] (NOLOCK) l2 ON cast(l2.PACKSLIP as decimal(22,8)) = cast(p.pickticket_number as decimal(22,8))
```

However, none of that or any combination of casting or converting seems to work. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly have invalid data.  You can find it by doing something like this:

```
select packslip
from [A1Warehouse].[dbo].[RF_LOG2]
where try_cast(l2.PACKSLIP as decimal(22,8)) is null and l2.PACKSLIP is not null;
```

As for your query, you can avoid the error by using `try_cast()`.  However, you should see what the actual problems in your data are.

And, your foreign key relationships should have matching types and be properly declared.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you have data that cannot be converted into a number/decimal

cast/convert as varchar

```
select top 100 
    pickticket_number,
    date_allocated,
    l2.action
from  
    [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].PickTickets P (nolock)
left join
    [A1Warehouse].[dbo].[RF_LOG2] (NOLOCK) l2 ON cast(l2.PACKSLIP as varchar) = cast(p.PickTicket_Number as varchar)
```

then troubleshoot each table to see what non numeric characters are in that field

by using `isnumeric`